# How can I Match SHA256 between classic asp and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp-classic, sha256

I am in the process of increasing a sites security to include sha256 encryption along with a salt in a classic ASP page. to do this i am using code from this site. http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2565

I will eventually upgrade the site to .net so i want to make sure i can match the encrypted password in both classic asp and .net.

In classic asp i am calling the encryption like so.

```
GeneratedNewPassword = SHA256(Password & Random & NewGuid)
```

and generated a password of this: 2551baf9ab959dcb4224b3c3080b5888e0866be1a53f4a123645b71020272a3c

I then tried to create this same thing in .net

```
string hashedPassword = Security.HashSha1(password + random + dbUserGuid);
SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create(); //utf8 here as well
byte[] bytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password + random + dbUserGuid));
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Which generated a string like this: fzC5FX4ShhZrdqy8MVM7PPVnW4D2gaX6DlinPDRFT2I=

I am guessing it has something to do with the utf that I am using, but not sure. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The classic ASP code doesn't convert the result to Base64 as you do in ASP.NET. You should use `BitConverter.ToString(byte []).ToLower().Replace("-", "")` instead of `Convert.ToBase64String(byte [])` and see if that yields a better result.

Comment: New code changed 
   `string result = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);`
That resulted in this being returned. 
7F-30-B9-15-7E-12-86-16-6B-76-AC-BC-31-53-3B-3C-F5-67-5B-80-F6-81-A5-FA-0E-58-A7-3C-34-45-4F-62

Comment: I tried your updated code and it still doesn't match.
609e858b3048011330828ee970c5aa97b18aa68af57626f19112591d9cdb50de

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake. My guid coming in from my database in classic asp was upper case and in .net it was lower case. Once I did a toUpper on the incoming guid my hashes matched.

Thanks for the help.